# How to scroll Recyclerview inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have recyclerview inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and I want it to be scrollable, but it is not. When I scroll, appbar is scrolling but not recyclerview. I tried different things, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/caves_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/caves_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/mount"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />



            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/WhiteToolbarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Found solution:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but this solution not working for me.Could you please help me with same.

Comment: Just as aditional info: this solution does not work on pre-lollipop devices

Answer (score 0):

Set The Horizontal Track as false in Appbarlayout

This Fixed the problem. Do Let me know if it's not working

Code

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="#fff"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText">
```