# Collapsable toolbar not collapsing properly when having recycler view inside it

Tags: android

I have a collapsableToolBar layout.The image inside the tolbar is collapsing and sliding but the items in recycler view are not collapsing,
   they remain at their position only.I want themto move to top and collapse.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/collapps_bar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >
            <View
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyClerView"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Hi stack Learner, did you find the answer? If not, it is correct what I said? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you managed to do that, but I'm going to suggest you what to do if you didn't.

First, change the `fill_parent` to `match_parent` because fill_parent is deprecated starting from API Level 8.

[As Nikoloz Akhvlediani said on his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330867/how-to-scroll-recyclerview-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout), you could use the method `addOnItemTouchListener` using your recycler view `recyClerView`, and then, call to `onInterceptTouchEvent` to get the touch events and `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` to disallow the touch events from the recycler view and get the desired scrolling.

For example, on `onCreate()` method, you could add this code

```
recyClerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() { // Listen to all actions
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // If you get some movement from a mouse, pen, finger or trackball
                    rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps :)